# Initialize a reference - warning C4355: 'this' : used in base member initializer list

Tags: c++

```
class A;

class B {
public:
    B(A& a) : a(a) {}
private:
    A& a;
};

/* Method 1 */
/* warning C4355: 'this' : used in base member initializer list */
/*
class A {
public:
    A() : b(*this) {}

private:
    B b;
};
*/

/* Method 2 */
/* But I need to manually perform memory dellocation. */
class A {
public:
    A() { b = new B(*this); }
    ~A() { delete b; }

private:
    B* b;
};

int main() {
}
```

Currently, when I try to initialize the reference in B, I am using Method 1. However, Method 1 will flag me warning which is understandable.

Hence, I have to fall back using Method 2, by using dynamic memory allocation.

Is there any better way I can use, without the need of manual memory allocation/ dellocation (OK. I know smart pointer)?

I prefer Method 1, just that I am not comfortable with the warning.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note this is a warning (so it is dangerous not illegal).

What the compiler is worried about is that you are passing a pointer for an object that has not been fully initialized. Thus if the pointer is used in the B class constructor you are in undefined behavior.

So if you do use this the only thing you can do is assign the pointer to a member variable (reference or pointer). **But note** be careful of the assignment to a variable as you may invoke an implicit cast (I am not sure if that is actually a problem but the RTTI is not available until the object is fully formed).

What are you trying to achieve by storing the reference?

Answer (score 11):

Doing this is valid.

However, you must ensure (I mean by yourself, there's no way the compiler can do this) that the `this` is not used to call virtual functions until the object is fully constructed.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what you're doing, a method might be to factor out the parts of `A` that `B` needs, than have `A` inherit from the part.

```
struct bar_base; // interface foo wants

struct foo
{
    foo(bar_base& pX) :
    mX(pX)
    {}

    bar_base& mX;
};

struct bar_base
{
    /* whatever else */ 
protected:
    bar_base& get_base(void)
    {
        // getting `this` went here; safe because bar_base is initialized
        return *this; 
    }
};

struct bar : bar_base
{
    bar(void) :
    // bar_base is already initialized, so:
    mX(get_base())
    {}

    foo mX;
};
```

Obviously, this depends on what you're doing. This makes sure you never get undefined behavior.

But really, it's just warning. If you promise to never use `this` in B's constructor, you're fine, and can silence the warning this way:

```
struct bar;

struct foo
{
    foo(bar& pX) :
    mX(pX)
    {}

    bar& mX;
};

struct bar
{
    bar(void) :
    mX(self())
    {}

    foo mX;

private:
    bar& self(void)
    {
        // fools the warning
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Make sure you know what you're doing, though. (Perhaps it could be re-designed?)

Answer (score 2):

Well, one obvious way to avoid the warning is to make B store a pointer-to-A, then you don't have to initialise it in B's constructor/A's initialiser list, and can wait until the body of A's constructor is executing....

Answer (score 0):

Take this warning seriously. Your `this` object is not yet fully constructed and passing around is not safe (if you ever accidentally call a function on `this` you invoke UB). Also, there are other techniques for memory management. Try looking up the STL design of allocators.

You could also use RAII/smart pointers to achieve the same effect.

Or, are you trying to write a garbage collector/memory profiler of sorts?