# How to prevent warning C4355: 'this' : used in base member initializer list

Tags: c++, constructor, this, compiler-warnings

my question is similar into [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509447/initialize-a-reference-warning-c4355-this-used-in-base-member-initializer), but I hadn't found info that I need. I have my class constructor.

```
CustomTreeViewItem::CustomTreeViewItem(CustomTreeView* list) 
    : m_childs(), m_expanded(false), m_list(list), m_components(), m_depth(1), 
    m_rect(), m_root(this)
{}
```

I use `this` pointer in constructor but do not call any methods from that so I do not invoke undefined behavior. So everything is fine, but I got warning, now I'm writing some lib (little framework) so I have to write error-free code. So I have changed my code into this:

```
CustomTreeViewItem::CustomTreeViewItem(CustomTreeView* list) 
    : m_childs(), m_expanded(false), m_list(list), m_components(), m_depth(1), 
    m_rect(), m_root(NULL)
{
    m_root = this;
}
```

Now I do not get any warning, however in this way I lose performance (very slightly, but anyway it is loss). I want to ask if there isn't any way to keep the highest performance and prevent this warning.

Comment: Are you sure that you lose performance with optimization enabled? Doesn't seem to make a difference for the assembly generated by g++ here. Also, you could use `#pragma` to disable warnings if you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @nijansen this will be used for new projects and for old (very old) so compilers variates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the pointer is only stored for later use, the Standard guarantees this is perfectly safe.

You likely will need to use a pragma to disable the warning.  And warning control is non-portable (other compilers will likely just ignore your pragma and continue to warn).

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that the compiler should not complain about that, the next thing is that the alternative version of the code, where the `m_root` is set to `NULL` (should be `nullptr`) and later to `this` will most probably not have a performance impact at all. Any optimizing compiler should be able to merge both writes into a single write with `this`. Take a look at the assembly. Even if that triggered an extra write, the variable is *hot*, so it is just an L1 write and the cost would not be noticeable.

Comment: Fully agree with that; and from what I've tested so far compilers agree with that as well if you compile with optimization enabled.