# Using parts of this (corresponding to base-class) to initialize a member

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Background:
I had something like (but with significant code in Z that I didn't want to change and the warning is enabled globally - I know I could disable it):

```
#pragma warning (error: 4355)
struct A;
struct B;
struct MapCompare {
   A*the;
   MapCompare(A*a):the(a) {;}
   bool operator()(int,int) const;
};
class Z {
  A a;
  B b;
  std::map<int,int,MapCompare> m;
public:
  Z():m{MapCompare{&a}} {;}
  ...
};
```

But I want to change to use both a and b inside MapCompare.
The less impactful variant seemed to be:

```
#pragma warning (error: 4355)
struct A;
struct B;
struct AB {
   A a;
   B b;
};
struct MapCompare {
   AB*the;
   MapCompare(AB*ab):the(ab) {;}
   bool operator()(int,int) const;
};
class Z : public AB {
  std::map<int,int,MapCompare> m;
public:
  Z():m{MapCompare{static_cast<AB*>(this)}} {;}
  ...
};
```

The error message is:

> error C4355: 'this': used in base member initializer list

So Visual Studio 2019 (16.9.5) complains about using `this` in an initializer, even though I only want the base-part that is initialized (see [Order of execution in constructor initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037219/order-of-execution-in-constructor-initialization-list) ).

Is there some way to tell this to the compiler (and not just disable the warning)? The work-around I found was:

```
#pragma warning (error: 4355)
struct A;
struct B;
struct AB {
   A a;
   B b;
};
struct MapCompare {
   AB*the;
   MapCompare(AB*ab):the(ab) {;}
   bool operator()(int,int) const;
};
class Z {
  AB ab;
  A&a;
  B&b;
  std::map<int,int,MapCompare> m;
public:
  Z():m{MapCompare{&ab}},a(ab.a),b(ab.b) {;}
  ...
};
```

Note: I tried to search for similar issues and found [Initialize a reference - warning C4355: 'this' : used in base member initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509447/initialize-a-reference-warning-c4355-this-used-in-base-member-initializer)
but the difference is that I want to extract the base-class part that has been initialized which makes it safe (as long as the members are in this order).

Comment: I did not receive 'this' warning when testing the snippet. Could you please check whether certain settings have been changed.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I updated - I believe I missed the code enabling that specific message. I also double-checked that I compiled with VS 2019, and added version information.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this situation which also goes wrong:

```
class z {
    int a = 5;
    int num;
public:
    z() :num(this->a) {}
};
```

According to the document [Compiler Warning C4355](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-c4355?view=msvc-170), this pointer cannot be used in the initializer list for a base class. This warning is off by default. What the snippet does is similar to the example provided: CDerived(): CBase(this). This object is not fully constructed and  is not safe to use (for the compiler). You need to give it an instance.

Comment: But in this example you can avoid the problem by write `z():num(a) {;}`, since `a` is initialized before `num`. I wanted something similar for using the base-class contents (where the base-class is an aggregate class without any virtual functions). I can understand that this is a too specialized case to implement in the compiler, but I just wanted to check.